# How to clear polygon from agm-map?

Tags: angular, drawing, polygon, polyline, agm

How can I clear polygon from the map when I clicked the clear button.

```
<agm-map [latitude]="40.034989"
         [longitude]="29.062844"
         [zoom]="15"
         [agmDrawingManager]="drawing"
         class="full-width-height">
    <agm-drawing-manager #drawing="agmDrawingManager"
                         [drawingMode]="'polygon'"></agm-drawing-manager>
</agm-map>
<button mat-mini-fab>
    <mat-icon (click)="onClearButtonClicked()">close</mat-icon>
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've solved it! 
overlay.setMap(null) works!

```
   public onOverlayComplete(e: any) {
        this.mArea = e.overlay;
    }

    public onClearButtonClicked() {
        this.mArea.setMap(null);
    }
```